# add callback finish function to multiple instance of jQuery Final Countdown

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to integrate the jQuery Final Countdown as it seems the multiple instance ability is the least system demanding.

Example code shows:

```
<div data-countdown="2020/01/01"></div>
<div data-countdown="2019/01/01"></div>
<div data-countdown="2018/01/01"></div>
<div data-countdown="2017/01/01"></div>

<script>
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
 var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
 $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {    
     $this.html(event.strftime(''
     + '<span>%w</span> weeks '
     + '<span>%d</span> days '
     + '<span>%H</span> hr '
     + '<span>%M</span> min '
     + '<span>%S</span> sec')); 
 });    
});
</script>
```

But the callback functionality is given an example as:

```
<div id="clock"></div>

$('#clock').countdown('2020/10/10 12:34:56')
 .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
     var format = '%H:%M:%S';
     if(event.offset.days > 0) {
         format = '%-d day%!d ' + format;
     }
     if(event.offset.weeks > 0) {
         format = '%-w week%!w ' + format;
     }
     $(this).html(event.strftime(format));
 })
 .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
     $(this).parent()
         .addClass('ending')
         .html('<strong>This offer has expired!</strong>');
 });
```

What I want to do is add the .on finish callback to the multiple instances (div data-countdown) but however I try to add the event it doesn't work and the countdown disappears from the screen.

How can I add the on finish callback to the  $('[data-countdown]').each(function() ?

Thanks for any help guys

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
$this.on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
     $(this).parent()
         //.addClass('disabled')
         .html('Example Callback text or add an alert or function up to you');
```

before the final `});` of the each function and the callback is applied to each instance of the countdown.

Answer (score -1):

```
  $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');

  $this.countdown(finalDate)
  $this.on('update.countdown', function(event){
    $this.html(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
  });
  $this.on('finish.countdown', function(event){
    alert("teste");
  });
});
```